# Do there exist base 'b' number systems, 1 < b < 2, that uniquely represent values for all finite terminating expansions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

It is known that the Golden Ratio base, and other generalized non-integer bases can represent the same value with multiple symbols/expansions. If we do not consider non-terminating symbols, i.e., 0.999999... , and only consider finite symbol representations, does there exists a base 'b', 1 < b < 2, where any finite symbol, terminating representation, of a value is unique?

Also for example, we know that binary symbols such as [1 0 0 0 1 1], which are finite and terminating, represent unique values, and that the same decimal value cannot be represented by another binary string. But if these strings were interpreted as 1*b^5 + 1*b^1 + 1^b^0, and we restrict coefficients to still be 0 or 1 (since 1 < b < 2), do we still have this property in general?  If not, do we have this property of uniqueness for a certain subset of 1 < b < 2?

Answer (score 2):

If $\sum_{j=0}^n a_j b^j = \sum_{j=0}^n c_j b^j$ with $a_j, c_j \in \{0,1\}$, then $b$ is a root of the polynomial $\sum_{j=0}^n d_j x^j$
where all $d_j \in \{-1,0,1\}$.  This can occur for $b \in (1,2)$.
For example, $X^2 - X - 1$ has the golden ratio $\phi$ as a root, which says $11$ and $100$ are equal in base $\phi$.
Similarly, $X^3 - X - 1$ has a root in $(1,2)$, approximately $1.324717957$, so for this base $b$ we have $1000 = 11$.

All such $b$ are roots of monic polynomials with integer coefficients, so they are algebraic integers.  For any $b$ that is not
an algebraic integer, terminating base-$b$ expansions will be unique. 
This includes transcendental numbers, and rationals that are not integers.

Comment: Thank you!  Follow-up question: If we continue to restrict 'n' to be finite, are there any theorems or proofs that guarantee a non-integer rational base 'b' on (1,2) will be at most "epsilon-close" to being a root of a monic polynomial for all finite terminating expansions with 'n' lte 'N'?  What I mean is that 'b' is a solution to an equation where a monic polynomial is set equal to "epsilon", rather than 0, and that 'b' can be a solution to that but 'eps' must be greater than some specific value given 'N' and 'b'? (I don't mean 'b' is close to an integer or irrational root by some epsilon)